# how to copy a lines from a file a file after matched string in a file using powershell script

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0

I have configuration yml file like below..I want to copy all lines till end of the file after matching string that is "logs: "

```
# numberof Threads
encryptionKey: "abcd"

logs:

  - displayName: "RLM_Failure"
    logDirectory: "/optware/msste/legaluat/log"
    logName: "DSSErrors.log"
    searchStrings:
        #displayName Should be unique across the patterns including the case.
       - displayName: "RLM_Dependency"
         pattern: "Merge fails entirely because needed objects"
         matchExactString: false
         caseSensitive: false
```

I tried with this command

```
Select-String "^logs: "/path/old/config.yml -Context 0, 100 | 
% {$_.Context.PostContext} | 
Add-Content "/path/new/config.yml"
```

But this is coping only100 lines after matched string... Is there anyway I can achieve without specifying line numbers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Read the file into a variable line by line, use the `.Where()` extension method in `SkipUntil` mode to grab everything except the lines preceding `logs:`, then use `Select-Object -Skip 1` to skip the `logs:` line itself:

```
$lines = Get-Content /path/old/config.yml

$lines.Where({$_ -match '^\s*logs:\s*(#|$)'}, 'SkipUntil') |Select-Object -Skip 1 |Set-Content /path/new/config.yml
```

Answer (score 0):

As alternative you can use `switch` like this:

```
$outputLine = $false
$newFile = switch -Regex -File '/path/old/config.yml' {
    '^logs:'  { $outputLine = $true }
    default   { if ($outputLine) { $_ }}
}

$newFile | Set-Content -Path '/path/new/config.yml'
```

OR

```
((Get-Content -Path '/path/old/config.yml' -Raw) -split '(?m)^logs:', 2)[-1] | 
Set-Content -Path '/path/new/config.yml'
```